# jquery drop option not working

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have used all my troubleshooting techniques but can't figure out why the drop event is not triggering. I am trying to get the "molecules" to drop in the "rxnCenter"

```
$(function(){
  $("#rxnCenter").droppable( {
    accept:'#rxnCenter', 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable("revert",false)
    }
  });
});


$(function() {
  $("molecule").draggable({
    appendTo: "#rxnCenter",
    revert:true,
    appendTo:'#rxnCenter'
  });
});
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: I think you have to give `molecule` as value for `accept` in the droppable instead of `#rxnCenter`

Comment: you have a <molecule> element? Interesting. Please tell me that your second selector is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `. or # molecule` as value for `accept` in the `droppable` instead of giving the value as `#rxnCenter`

Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fuDCB/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to accept the draggable thing in the droppable accept option.
Try this, It may work.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#rxnCenter").droppable( {
    accept:'molecule', 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable("revert",false)
    }
  });
});
```